# Liferay 6.0 to 6.1 upgrade process issues

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

During upgrade liferay due to some exception my liferay upgrade stops. Please check the link for the details of log file http://kl1p.com/up_6_0_6_1. I have done specific changes that we have to do in portal-ext.properties too. Not sure what we have to put for "upgrade.processes = XXX".

Comment: These are common exception in the logs I checked on google these are the common error faced by people (e.g.                                   ERROR [ImageProcessorImpl:181] com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.FileExtensionException:
document_thumbnail/0/13/127/425741/2465320
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: 
Duplicate entry '10249-19925-image_gallery' for key 'IX_ED5CA615')        But unfortunately I am not able to solve the problem by those comments and suggestion :(  If anyone can suggest me proper steps for this would be great help for me.

Comment: I found upgrade.processes=com.liferay.portal.upgrade.UpgradeProcess_6_0_12_to_6_1_0,com.liferay.portal.upgrade.UpgradeProcess_6_1_1 property for Liferay 6.0 EE to 6.1 EE. What I have to add for Liferay 6.0.6 CE to liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-ga1 ?

Answer (score 0):

The following is what the portal.properties contain for 6.1:

```
upgrade.processes=\
        com.liferay.portal.upgrade.UpgradeProcess_5_0_0,\
        com.liferay.portal.upgrade.UpgradeProcess_5_1_0,\
        com.liferay.portal.upgrade.UpgradeProcess_5_1_2,\
        com.liferay.portal.upgrade.UpgradeProcess_5_2_0,\
        com.liferay.portal.upgrade.UpgradeProcess_5_2_1,\
        com.liferay.portal.upgrade.UpgradeProcess_5_2_2,\
        com.liferay.portal.upgrade.UpgradeProcess_5_2_3,\
        com.liferay.portal.upgrade.UpgradeProcess_6_0_0,\
        com.liferay.portal.upgrade.UpgradeProcess_6_0_1,\
        com.liferay.portal.upgrade.UpgradeProcess_6_0_2,\
        com.liferay.portal.upgrade.UpgradeProcess_6_0_3,\
        com.liferay.portal.upgrade.UpgradeProcess_6_0_5,\
        com.liferay.portal.upgrade.UpgradeProcess_6_0_6,\
        com.liferay.portal.upgrade.UpgradeProcess_6_1_0
```

**com.liferay.portal.upgrade.UpgradeProcess_6_1_0** this is fine.

So you don't need to set anything in your portal-ext.properties for this field for upgrading to 6.1.

As for the errors they are usual as you mentioned as there are a lot of changes int the Doc library portlet and Image portlet from 6.0 to 6.1.

Comment: Can you suggest me what I have to do for the above mentioned errors or any suggestion to avoid it during upgrade?

Comment: try making the property: verify.frequency=1 to verify.frequency=0, and check if the errors are thrown. I probably think the errors are thrown during verification of the database and this property disables the verification.

Comment: Please check the link http://www.liferay.com/zh/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/12227463 , in this link it is suggested to add "dlFileVersion.setExtension(extension); // NEW LINE" this line but i am not getting the location where I have to add these lines? can you provide me the location of the file?

Comment: the post mentions this class: com.liferay.portal.upgrade.v6_1_0.UpgradeDocumentLibrary, obtain the liferay source code and update this class, at line 450 add that line of code inside the method updateThumbnails().

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question but I am not able to find the location of file for "com.liferay.portal.upgrade.v6_1_0.UpgradeDocumentLibrary" and also you have not mentioned in which file I have to add  "verify.frequency=0". I have already searched the relevant text in the folder by "AgentRansack". Any idea?

Comment: verify.frequency in portal-ext.properties. And the class is in portal-impl.jar so if you download liferay's source code you can find it in portal-impl folder.

Comment: Thanks Prakash for your quick response. Can you help me in compiling "UpgradeDocumentLibrary.java" & packing it into portal-impl.jar ?

Comment: I have downloaded the source file for "UpgradeDocumentLibrary.java" and when I am trying to compile it is giving error. Can you suggest me what is the proper way of compiling this file. I am using command line for compiling. May be it is simple but I am missing something as I am new to JAVA and Liferay :(

Comment: from command line you need to have all the jars in ROOT/WEB-INF/lib in classpath for compilation and then after compiling create a jar with this class and put it in ROOT/WEB-INF/lib. Or you can create an ext plugin since this class is in portal-impl.jar

Comment: FileExtensionException is solved but still MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException is there any idea. I have checked the respective table in the database. Please check my new log file http://kl1p.com/8Af

Comment: This error may be because you had run the upgrade many times and it has already made changes to the database.

Comment: If I am adding "permissions.user.check.algorithm=5" in portal-ext.properties I am able to do the upgarde with few exception. I just want to know your comments regarding this log file message "Liferay is configured to use permission algorithm 5. Versions after 6.1 will only support algorithm 6 and above. Please sign in as an administrator, go to the Control Panel, select "Server Administration", select the "Data Migration" tab, and convert from this legacy permission algorithm as soon as possible.".